# Spring cloud composite bootstrap.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, application.properties

Is there any way how to "build" `bootstrap.yml` from multiple `yaml` files?

Here is my scenario, I have a bunch of `micro-services` and every service had the same `bootstrap.yml` properties expect `spring.application.name`.

I would like to split my `bootstrap.yml` into two files, `base-bootstrap.yml` which contains config service configuration like URI, password ... etc and then `bootstrap.yml` which could contain `spring.application.name` or whatever else.

`base-bootstrap.yml` file could be externalized in some dependency jar and should be used like default, `bootstrap.yml` should override any value. Here is some sample:

**base-boostrap.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop
      uri: http://config
      password: ${CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD:password}
      fail-fast: true
---
spring:
  profiles: production
  cloud:
    config:
      label: master
      password: ${CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD}
---
spring:
  profiles: development
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application.name: sample-service
  cloud:
    config:
      label: release/1.0.1
---
spring:
  profiles: production
  cloud:
    config:
      label: 1.1.0
```

Could anyone please guide me how to do it?

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't override bootstrap config, I think spring boot probably doesn't support such functionality.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981861/how-do-you-properly-set-different-spring-profiles-in-bootstrap-file-for-spring