# How can we set different environment profile in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config, spring-profiles

I am working on `microservices` using `spring boot`. i have around 5 `microservices`. so I configured spring cloud config server to centralized configuration. its perfectly working fine.

**config server configuretion**

> spring.profiles.active=native
>
> spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/common-config
>
> server.port=8888

now the problem is I have two environment `dev` and `test` and i created `application-test.properties`  and `application-dev.properties` as per the spring documented i need to set profile like

**Spring profile**

> spring.profiles.active=test

but its already set as a native then how can i load multiple profile.

please help me ..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the active profile name as an environment variable at run time of each of the apps. This will take priority over the active profile listed in your properties file. You can do this with any property actually. If you're using docker to launch your apps, you can pass it in from your Dockerfile or from your docker-compose.yml

Comment: yes i tried this but its not getting profile and throwing db url related error

Comment: Hmm ok! Please could you provide an example of how you're passing the environment variables in? Oh and it might be worth moving the profile name to the bootstrap.properties file as it's loaded earlier

Comment: The examples on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981861/how-do-you-properly-set-different-spring-profiles-in-bootstrap-file-for-spring might be useful here

Answer (score 0):

You can set spring.profiles.active=$ACTIVE_SPRING_PROFILE and set OS environment ACTIVE_SPRING_PROFILE = test

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple profiles in Spring. Try:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,native
```

See more: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles

Comment: its throwing me same error "determine embedded database url for database type NONE" (no profiles are currently active)

Comment: You probably didn't provide enough information to auto-configure a DataSource. Or maybe if you are not using database access - you should not add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa to pom (sometimes can be copied there by mistake). Anyway it's hard to guess without source code.